# Why does $\|(I+A^{-1}E)x\| = \|x-A^{-1}Ex\|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

I was reading Lecture 15 of G.W. Stewart's Afternotes on Numerical Analysis, and he states the following theorem with proof:

"Let $A$ be nonsingular. If

$\|A^{-1}E\| < 1$, (15.3)

then $A+E$ is nonsingular.

To establish this result, we will show that under the condition (15.3) if $x \neq 0$ then $(A+E)x \neq 0$. Since $A$ is nonsingular $(A+E)x = A(I+A^{-1}E)x \neq 0$ if and only if $(I+A^{-1}E)x \neq 0$. But

$\|(I+A^{-1}E)x\| = \|x-A^{-1}Ex\| \geq \|x\| - \|A^{-1}E\|\|x\| = (1-\|A^{-1}E\|)\|x\| > 0$, which establishes the result."

What I don't understand about this proof is the step where he states that $\|(I+A^{-1}E)x\| = \|x-A^{-1}Ex\|$. This implies that $\|x+A^{-1}Ex\|=\|x-A^{-1}Ex\|$, and it's certainly not generally true for arbitrary vectors $a$ and $b$ that $\|a+b\| = \|a-b\|$.

In fact, I think that if we have that $\|a+b\| = \|a-b\|$, then this would imply that $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal, since then we would have $\|a+b\|^2 = \|a-b\|^2 \Rightarrow \|a\|^2+\|b\|^2 - 2\|a\|\|b\| \cos (\theta_1) = \|a\|^2+\|b\|^2 - 2\|a\|\|b\| \cos(\theta_2)$

by the Law of Cosines and because $\|b\|=\|-b\|$, where $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ must be supplementary angles since $\theta_1$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$ and $\theta_2$ is the angle between $a$ and $-b$. Solving this tells us that $\cos (\theta_1) = \cos (\theta_2)$, and, taking $0 \leq \theta_1, \theta_2 \leq \pi$, we have that $\theta_1 = \theta_2$. Combining this with the fact that $\theta_1 + \theta_2 = \pi$, since they are supplementary, we have that $\theta_1 = \theta_2 = \pi/2$, which implies that $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal.

All that said, I don't see why it should be the case that $x$ and $A^{-1}Ex$ are orthogonal. The only conditions that Stewart requires for this theorem are that $A$ be nonsingular and $\|A^{-1}E\| < 1$. I'm not sure if there's something else I'm missing or some other explanation for this. Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is most likely a typo. It can be fixed easily-

$$\|(I+A^{-1}E)x\| = \|x\color{red}+A^{-1}Ex\| \geq \|x\| - \|A^{-1}E\|\|x\| = (1-\|A^{-1}E\|)||x|| > 0$$
and the inequality immediately following the modified step follows just from $\|My\| \le \|M\|\|y\|$ and
$ \|a+b\|\ge \|a\|-\|b\|$ which of course is just triangle inequality (in the form $\|a\| = \|(-b) + (a+b)\| \le \|{-b}\| + \|a+b\|$).

Comment: You beat me to the punch!

Answer (score 2):

If $||x+A^{-1}Ex||=||x-A^{-1}Ex||$ then we would have to have $$\big<x-A^{-1}Ex,x-A^{-1}Ex\big>=\big<x+A^{-1}Ex,x+A^{-1}Ex\big>$$ which means $$||x||^2-2\big<x,A^{-1}E\big>+||A^{-1}Ex||^2=||x||^2+2\big<x,A^{-1}E\big>+||A^{-1}Ex||^2$$ This is only true if $\big<x,A^{-1}E\big>=0$ i.e. $x$ and $A^{-1}Ex$ are orthogonal. However, since $$||x+y|| \geq \Big|||x||-||y||\Big|$$ is true for any $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ I don't even see this this intermediate step is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly standard trick assuming that $\|\cdot \|$ is a submultiplicative norm.

Since $\|A^{-1}E\| < 1$, the matrix $D=\sum_{k=0}^\infty ((-A^{-1}E )^k $ is well defined
and since $D (I+A^{-1}E) = I$ we see that $D$ is invertible. Then we have
$DA^{-1} (A+E) = I$ and so $A+E$ is invertible with $(A+E)^{-1} = D A^{-1}$.